# Why does calling the __exit__ method on unittest.mock._patch throw an IndexError?

Tags: python, patch, with-statement, contextmanager

When I define a function and patch it using the `with` statement it runs fine.

```
def some_func():
  print('this is some_func')

with patch('__main__.some_func', return_value='this is patched some_func'):
  some_func()
```

Output:

```
this is patched some_func
```

My understanding is that using the `with` statement would cause the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods to be called on the patch object. So I thought that would be equivalent to doing this:

```
patched_some_func = patch('__main__.some_func', return_value='this is patched some_func')
patched_some_func.__enter__()
some_func()
patched_some_func.__exit__()
```

The output from the `some_func` call is the same in this case:

```
this is patched some_func
```

But I get an `IndexError` when I call the `__exit__` method:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/unittest/mock.py", line 1437, in __exit__
    return exit_stack.__exit__(*exc_info)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 482, in __exit__
    received_exc = exc_details[0] is not None
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Why am I getting an `IndexError` in the second case but not the first where I use `with`?
(An additional note, I get this error on python 3.7.10 but not on python 3.7.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is incorrect; on exit the context manager `__exit__` method is passed `None, None, None`:

```
patched_some_func.__exit__(None, None, None)
```

The arguments are *always* passed in, either the exception information, or `None` for each of the three arguments. See the [documentation on `object.__exit__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__exit__):

> If the context was exited without an exception, all three arguments will be `None`.

Also see the [*PEP 343 – The “with” Statement* specification section](https://peps.python.org/pep-0343/#specification-the-with-statement):

> The calling convention for `mgr.__exit__()` is as follows. If the finally-suite was reached through normal completion of `BLOCK` or through a non-local goto (a `break`, `continue` or `return` statement in `BLOCK`), `mgr.__exit__()` is called with three `None` arguments. If the finally-suite was reached through an exception raised in `BLOCK`, `mgr.__exit__()` is called with three arguments representing the exception type, value, and traceback.

As to why you get an index error in 3.7.10: the `mock.patch()` implementation in older releases used [an incorrect implementation  that could result in an unexpected exception](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/84307), and the [fix for this](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/19484) was to use an [`contextlib.ExitStack()` instance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack). The `ExitStack` context manager uses [`def __exit__(self, *exc_details):` as the method signature](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4b47a5b6ba66b02df9392feb97b8ead916f8c1fa/Lib/contextlib.py#L481-L528) and expects the `exc_details` tuple to have at least 1 element in it, which normally is either `None` or an exception object. The bug fix is part of Python 3.7.8, which is why you don't see the same context manager in 3.7.3 as you see in 3.7.10. In [the older version of the code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d7c567b08f9d7d6aef21b881340a2b72731129db/Lib/unittest/mock.py#L1428-L1449), the patcher `__exit__()` method also uses a catchall `*args` tuple, but otherwise doesn't try to index into this tuple.